# Rewriting static resources url in .htaccess for CDN

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have an existing live application based on php/Mysql/apache stack. A quick performance evaluation revealed that a CDN solution would help us gain a lot of speed. Planning to use cloudfront for the CDN.

The issue is existing code wasnt written with CDN in mind.

At the moment, our html outputs contain statuc resources under link tags and are referenced with "./images/test.png" etc...

is there anyway to identify these links just before sending the output and replace it to load from local CDN url.

Comment: The simplest solution would probably be to just run the entire site through CloudFront.  Caching can be enabled/disabled for static/dynamic content based on path pattern matching.  Have you considered that?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for this. How do i run the site through cloudfront. Can you give me some terms so that i can search for. cloudfront is confusing to be because there are just numerous sub sections and terms. Is this the same as changing my nameservers to use amazon's and work through them ?